# Why is useEffect render-blocking(paint-blocking) in the tooltip example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, browser

I am following the [tooltip example](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect#measuring-layout-before-the-browser-repaints-the-screen) for the `useLayoutEffect` hook from the new react docs. From their explanation, I assume that the following is the order of execution of things:

**react render() --> reconciliation --> update DOM if virtual dom is changed --> DOM update finishes --> useLayoutEffect is executed --> broswer paints and triggers some sort of LayoutPaint event --> useEffect is triggered**

To verify this, I swapped `useLayouteffect` hook with `useEffect` hook in the tooltip.js file of the docs example.

[This is the modified example](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-driscoll-nxmj3q?file=/Tooltip.js)

I have put a few `for` loops to slow down the execution of `useEffect` hook. Now when you load the modifed example and move your mouse over to any of the three buttons, you will see first paint with tooltip in wrong position and then the useEffect takes 1-2s and then you will see another repaint with the tooltip at correct position. So far so good, but now any later mouseovers on the same button, you will see that the wrong-position-paint waits for useEffect to finish and then the correct-position-paint happens within a few miliseconds.

[image]

So I have two questions:

1. Why does later mouseovers cause `useEffect` to become render-blocking?
2. How does react make sure that `useLayoutEffect` stops browser paint from happening and if any state update within `useLayoutEffect` is mentioned then triggers another render->repaint while completely disallowing the previous browser paint to occur at all. In our case the tooltip at -60px is not painted at all.

Comment: You can always read the ReactJS source code to figure this out.

Comment: @jcubic I tried, but it's too much for me. I tried to find source code for `useRef` but couldn't find, for instance. For the time being I have to resort to stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't think that you will find React core developers here that will answer your question. You can try asking on the ReactjS repo in the discussions on GitHub.

Comment: @jcubic Here I go https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/issues/6113 I noticed even with my other questions on react, there aren't many react experts active on stackoverflow.

Comment: There are tousands of questions on StackOverflow asked every day, you can't answer all of them, especially if the question is about the internals of React. There are not many people that know React internals not only on StackOverflow. You can write to some Core developers (like Dan Abramov) on Twitter you may get a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: You are using React v18 ? Can you test with React v17, to counter-check ? Probably the `useEffect` is executed synchronously because the mouse-over is a _user event_, as per https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24195: _"React now ... synchronously flushes effect functions if ... triggered during a discrete user input event ..."_

Answer (score 0):

1. The `useEffect` hook isn't normally render-blocking. However, if heavy computation occurs within the hook, it may cause significant lag and appear as if it's blocking rendering. In your case, nested loops within the `useEffect` are likely causing this behavior.
2. `useLayoutEffect` runs synchronously after DOM mutations but before the browser paints. If a state update occurs within `useLayoutEffect`, React flushes this state update immediately after `useLayoutEffect` finishes, causing a synchronous re-render before the browser gets a chance to paint. This prevents intermediate states (like the tooltip at -60px) from being painted.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import TooltipContainer from "./TooltipContainer.js";

export default function Tooltip({ children, targetRect }) {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [tooltipHeight, setTooltipHeight] = useState(60);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const { height } = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      setTooltipHeight(height);
    }
  }, [targetRect]); // Re-run this effect when targetRect changes

  let tooltipX = 0;
  let tooltipY = 0;
  if (targetRect !== null) {
    tooltipX = targetRect.left;
    tooltipY = targetRect.top - tooltipHeight;
    if (tooltipY < 0) {
      // It doesn't fit above, so place below.
      tooltipY = targetRect.bottom;
    }
  }

  return createPortal(
    <TooltipContainer x={tooltipX} y={tooltipY} contentRef={ref}>
      {children}
    </TooltipContainer>,
    document.body
  );
}
```

Comment: "_However, if heavy computation occurs within the hook, it may cause significant lag and appear as if it's blocking rendering_" I don't think that's correct, `useEffect` is fired after the browser paint is finished -- the tooltip should be shown before `useEffect` is executed.

Comment: The perceived "blocking" effect in your useEffect is due to the heavy computational load of your loops, which delays other tasks in JavaScript's single-threaded environment, including rendering. However, useEffect does normally run after painting.

useLayoutEffect runs immediately after DOM updates but before painting, hence you never see the tooltip at -60px, as its position is adjusted in useLayoutEffect before painting happens. React's concurrent mode and browser optimizations can influence these timings.